# I drew a wolrdmap with python and I want to see the data when I click on a country with the mouse

Tags: python, sql, data-visualization

I drew a worldamp with Python here is my code

```
test2=pd.read_sql_query('''select nicename,year,value as value from bsa,countries where country=nicename ''',cx.conn)

with open('pays.json') as json_file:
data = json.load(json_file)

fig = px.choropleth(data_frame = test2,geojson=data, locations='nicename',color='value',locationmode='country names',
                color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma,
                title='Regions with Positive Cases',animation_frame='year',
                #labels={'value':'value bsa'}
                      )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
config = dict({'scrollZoom': True})
fig.show(config=config)
```

Here is a screenshot of my result:

[image: my picture]

When I click on France for example, I want it to display a graph to visualize my data, in x-axis I put the year, and on the y-axis I want to put value.

Knowing that my BSA table has a structure like this :

```
country   year   value 
france     2010   10 
france     2011    12 
france     2013    13 
france     2014    14 
france     2015    16
```

thank you for any help !

Comment: Hello and welcome ! Which data visualitation library do you use ?

Comment: @CharybdeBE Hello ,  I use matplotlib.pyplot